# ActionBar color not changing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, material-design

I'm trying to change the color of the ActionBar in my app. The color was changed in the preview tap when opening the layout file, but not when I run it on my device (5.0.1). I need the status bar to be also colored.

Here is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Test" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TestActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TestActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <!--<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_dark</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_darker</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>

        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/iron</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/iron</item>

        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_darker</item>
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_darker</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Dark.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/iron</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

My manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.motassem.beacontest" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar" >        
        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My layout.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="com.example.motassem.beacontest.HomeActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <fragment     android:name="com.example.motassem.beacontest.HomeActivityFragment"
        android:id="@+id/frag_total"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my fragment.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/string_total_saved"
    android:id="@+id/tvTotal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTotal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**Edit**
After adding AppTheme in the solution's style.xml, the action bar is missing.

[image]

Comment: Which Activity are you using? You are setting a Material Theme in your Application tag, and a different one in SignupActivity.

Comment: yes as gabrield mentioned .. past your code please

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti
Thank you guys I changed the app theme and it worked. But the status bar is still not colored..

Comment: @MotassemJa which theme are you using now?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Test theme, in my styles.xml

Comment: @MotassemJa  Use an AppCompat theme and set the colorPrimaryDark. Check the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Activity` (which has to extend an `AppCompatActivity`) or in your `Application` you should use a `AppCompat` Theme.

If you are not using a `Toolbar` in your layout use somenthing like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
         <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
         <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
         <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Otherwise, if you are using a `Toolbar` use:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Updated. It depends if you are using a Toolbar in your layout or not.

Comment: Which theme have you applied to your activity?

Comment: @MotassemJa As described in the answer, you have to use it, if you are using a Toolbar in your layout, with setSupportActionBar(toolbar).

Comment: This codelab says material theme should work... https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-change-app-theme?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-change-app-theme#3

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to style.xml and applied it for my activity

```
<style name="Accelerator" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_darker</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```